# Brother MFC-J470DW (network printer) not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, printing, brother

I have a Brother MFC-J470DW network printer. For some reason the printer won't print. I have correctly downloaded the drivers using the install tool on the Brother website. I entered the IP address and got the confirmation

```
lpadmin -p MFCJ470DW -v socket://192.168.1.77
```

I have got the printer to work many times using this method. This time a test page would not print. I do not have a clue why it does not work this time. I might add that I have a ubuntu pro setup which I did not have before. I am not sure if this might be the problem.

If I issue the following commands a printer is clearily recognized.

```
lpstat 

MFCJ470DW-13            cbx             24576   Mon 14 Aug 2023 20:06:20
```

```
sudo ss -tulp

0.0.0.0:631                                  0.0.0.0:*             users:(("cups-browsed",pid=1601,fd=7))
```

However if I run

```
http://localhost:631/printers/?
```

I get the following:

```
Queue Name  Description Location    Make and Model  Status
MFCJ470DW   MFCJ470DW       Brother MFC-J470DW CUPS Processing - "The printer may not exist or is unavailable at this time."
```

If I open printer on Ubuntu 22.04 and go onto Printer State. I also get: `Processing - The printer may not exist or is unavailable at this time.`
I have also run

```
journalctl -f -u cups
```

and get the following error:

```
hpfax[10582]: [10582]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
```

Not sure if this is important.
Any help is greatly appreciate.

I was able to solve the problem. I just had to turn the printer off and on again as I realized I was not able to ping the printer. After that I reinstalled the drivers using the install tool on the Brother website.

Output  of  `lpstat -l -e && lpstat -t` is now:

```
Brother-MFC-J470DW permanent ipp://localhost/printers/Brother-MFC-J470DW dnssd://Brother%20MFC-J470DW._printer._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-8056f2a26ad0
Brother_MFC_J470DW network none ipp://Brother%20MFC-J470DW._ipp._tcp.local/
scheduler is running
system default destination: Brother-MFC-J470DW
device for Brother-MFC-J470DW: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-J470DW._printer._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-8056f2a26ad0
device for Brother_MFC_J470DW: implicitclass://Brother_MFC_J470DW/
Brother-MFC-J470DW accepting requests since Tue 15 Aug 2023 19:43:38
Brother_MFC_J470DW accepting requests since Wed 16 Aug 2023 06:27:02
printer Brother-MFC-J470DW is idle.  enabled since Tue 15 Aug 2023 19:43:38
printer Brother_MFC_J470DW is idle.  enabled since Wed 16 Aug 2023 06:27:02
```

Comment: Please add the outputs f `lpstat -l -e` and `lpstat -t` to your original info.